# Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method - Access Form - Can't find error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm pretty rusty with Access and I'm trying to design a database in order to track some service records and maintenance tasks for our Dive Shop.  Anyway, when I open `frmService` from a button on `frmWelcome` I get an error saying `OBJECT DOESN'T SUPPORT THIS PROPERTY OR METHOD`.  I Googled it, looked on here, and had a ton of different ideas to try, but for the life of me, I Can't find the error.


So, basically, I'm not even sure where to start looking.  I'm terrible at references to forms/subforms/etc., so the likelihood of the issue lying in there would be pretty high.  Making the assumption that it's an OnLoad issue with `frmService` I can only guess this is the code that's incorrect:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo Form_Load_Err
    lblTitle.Caption = "Service Record - " & Me.txtTask.Value
Form_Load_Exit:
    Exit Sub
Form_Load_Err:
   MsgBox Error$
    Resume Form_Load_Exit
End Sub
```

One thing to note, the Caption code DOES work.  Is there any other part of the form that could cause this?  I use several subforms but none of which have any code outside of simple macros created through Access.  I haven't converted them to VBA yet.

Comment: In the vba editor try to compile the code - hopefully that will jump to the offending line - I don't think it's an error in this routine, it looks like a syntax error elsewhere.

Comment: I did that and nothing came up, it compiled just fine.

Comment: it that case perhaps it's one of the macros  attempting to refer to  an object that no longer exists? Are any of those called when the form is opened, or when the button is pressed?

Comment: What is `Error$`?

Comment: It could be that the error handler is responding to another error from the object/routine that called this. Hard to say without more information.

Comment: Provide the code behind the button in `frmWelcome`, please? You can use the [edit] link below the question to add additional information.

Comment: Also, you might try commenting out ALL error handling in any code that is in any way related to these forms. Then when the error occurs VBA should take you to the line that's the cause.

Comment: Or set a breakpoint in the button procedure and step through code. But why use VBA? Why not simply a label with caption `Service Record - ` next to textbox or a textbox with expression that concatenates: `="Service Record - " & [txtTask]`?

Comment: Hey guys - I ended up finding out that the error was something entirely unrelated and I got it worked out.  What is was, I have no idea, but I managed to fix it while reviewing and trimming up some code.  Thanks a ton for the help!!